# converting dates to datetime2

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

Within my 'Sample' table, I have a 'Date' column that is nvarchar which I would like to convert to `ISO 8601 datetime2` format.

The date format that I have right now looks like this:

```
01-JAN-20 12.00.00.0000000AM
```

What is the code to convert this into `ISO 8601 datetime2` format?

Comment: ***NEVER***, **ever** store date or date/time values in `varchar` columns. Do you have a chance to fix that broken data model? Once it has the correct data type, you can format it to any output you like

Comment: unfortunately, i won't be able to fix it as i was tasked to change what's already in the database as much as possible without reuploading the data (it has more than 2 million records...)

Comment: `What is the code to convert this into ISO 8601 datetime2 format?` Have you tried looking up that in the documentation ?

Comment: @Squirrel - i'm a new SQL what do you mean "what is the code to convert this into ISO 8601"?

Answer (score 0):

ISO 8601 is a string format specification for date/time values whereas `datetime2` is an internal binary value.

To convert a dd-mon-yy formatted date string into a `datetime2` value and then format that value as an ISO 8601 date/time string, you can use:

```
FORMAT(CAST('01-JAN-20' AS datetime2), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffff').
```

Be aware the 2-digit year is ambiguous and will be interpreted according to the instance [2-digit year cut-off configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-two-digit-year-cutoff-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: thanks dan! what if i wanted to convert the entire column? would i have to do this one by one then since i think the above formula would only convert values with 01-JAN-20?

Comment: @ageee9, the snippet in my answer is just an example. To actually update the column value in the table, specify the column name instead of literal: `UPDATE dbo.YourTable SET DateColumn = FORMAT(CAST(DateColumn AS datetime2), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffff');`. This assumes all the currently values are properly formatted. Otherwise, you will need to use `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT` and decide what you want to do with invalid values.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is pretty smart about conversions without formats.  The following seems to work:

```
select convert(datetime2, left('01-JAN-20 12.00.00.0000000AM', 9))
```

Note:  This puts the value at midnight, because you describe the value as a "date", which I assume has no time component.